# Ordering by additional data in Elasticsearch. Is it possible?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I want search all results in list --

```
# [ [num, pk], [1, 34], [2, 3147] ...]
# num = [0, 1, 2, ... 7]
pks = [34, 3147,..., 1264]
```

I want search where `related__in=pks`, but like this.
First `.filter(related=pk[0])`, then `.filter(related=pk[1])`... And concatenate results to single query.

SO:

Can I add some filed/data to searchqueryset to sort by it later?

Or maybe concatenate many searchquerysets to one?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a [Haystack `MultiValueField`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=multivaluefield#subclasses) that allow for search engines to query ManyToMany relations like you are hinting at in your answer.

This is [demonstrated in the documentation like so](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html):

```
class NoteIndex(SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='user')
    categories = MultiValueField()
```

For details on how to efficiently query this field, [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058693/filtering-for-multiple-values-in-a-multivaluefield-in-django-haystack).

Comment: I need as multivalue, but with ordering as in list.
first all items related to first pk, then to second, third...